# What's wrong with my Google Spreadsheet Script?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script to automatically take information from a google sheet and put each row of data into individual, formatted docs. However when I run the script it either populates the data as "DOB" (in the date of birth spot) or as a different value. I am not a very good programmer and any help is appreciated. Thanks,

```
function createDocument() {
  var headers =Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1oycOOxDIAhbAI6Yq54KF4GAnjfVcttywYXOpKDBLHag', ('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'H1', 'I1', 'N1', 'O1'));
  var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1oycOOxDIAhbAI6Yq54KF4GAnjfVcttywYXOpKDBLHag', ('A4:O14'));
  var templateId = '1NJQHx4TWRQ3EQle5aLr-QV4uqD-tSR8TMP2-f6QjPmY';

  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){

    var Patient_name = tactics.values[i][0];

    var Date_Scheduled = tactics.values[i][0];

    var Surgery_Posting = tactics.values[i][0];

    var Start_Time = tactics.values[i][0];

    var Hospital = tactics.values[i][0];

    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();

    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(Patient_name + ' Surgery Posting');

    //Get the document body as a variable
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

    //Insert the Patient_name
    body.replaceText('##Patient_name##', Patient_name)

     //Insert the Date_Scheduled
    body.replaceText('##Date_Scheduled##', Date_Scheduled)

     //Insert the Surgery_Posting
    body.replaceText('##Surgery_Posting##', Surgery_Posting)

     //Insert the Start_Time
    body.replaceText('##Start_Time##', Start_Time)

     //Insert the Hospital
    body.replaceText('##Hospital##', Hospital)

    //Append tactics
    parseTactics(headers.values[0], tactics.values[i], body);

  }

}

function parseTactics(headers, tactics, body){ 

  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.length; i++){
    {tactics[i] != '' && 
      body.appendListItem(headers[i] + ' | ' + tactics[i] + ' net').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The column position after the iterator was not changed to the next column.

```
var Patient_name = tactics.values[i][0];

var Date_Scheduled = tactics.values[i][1]; //this last part the 0 to 1
```